# Add an attribute to output XML using something similar to call-template

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been searching for a few weeks now, and I've just about given up. I have an XSLT script to output an XML file based on an XSD definition. My problem lies with this bit of code:

Sample input, types can be arbitrarily nested:

```
<xs:element name="rootElement">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="r1" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element ref="r2" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element ref="r3" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
             <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element ref="r4" minOccurs="0" />
                 <xs:element ref="r5" minOccurs="0" />
             </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

XSL:

```
    <!-- I wish this could work -->
    <xsl:if test="$minOccurs">
        <xsl:attribute name="minOccurs"><xsl:value-of select="$minOccurs"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@ref">
            <xsl:variable name="elementRef" select="current()/@ref"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="//xs:element[@name=$elementRef]">
                    <xsl:call-template name="element">
                        <xsl:with-param name="minOccurs" select="./@minOccurs"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- abridged -->
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Output something like:

```
<rootElement>
    <r1 minOccurs="0" />
    <r2 minOccurs="0" />
    <r3 minOccurs="0">
        <r4/>
        <r5/>
    </r3>
</rootElement>
```

I'm doing a recursive call with , which works just fine. But, I can't add an attribute, and I've read just as much online. So how can I change this to be able to add an attribute?

Comment: How is it failing? Your code doesn't have enough context to be able to see what's wrong, e.g. we see references to variables but the declarations have been omitted.

Comment: I get the correct structure, with elements, just not the attribute minOccurs.

Comment: Well, since we can't see the template with name="element", how can we tell you what's wrong with it?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I see there's another mistake. This is confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this XML input,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="rootElement">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <!-- replaced original @ref with @name -->
        <xs:element name="r1" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="r2" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="r3" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="r4" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="r5" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

the following XSLT,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="xs:element">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:if test="@minOccurs">
        <xsl:attribute name="minOccurs">
          <xsl:value-of select="@minOccurs"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce the following XML output,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootElement>
   <r1 minOccurs="0"/>
   <r2 minOccurs="0"/>
   <r3 minOccurs="0">
      <r4 minOccurs="0"/>
      <r5 minOccurs="0"/>
   </r3>
</rootElement>
```

as requested.